# Spring conditional bean lookup

Tags: java, spring

There are some services :

```
@Service("first")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class FirstService extends AbstractService{
 // ...
}

@Service("second")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class SecondService extedns AbstractService{
 // ...
}

@Component
class Factory {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext context;    

  public AbstractService getService(boolean businessCondition){
    if (condition){
      return context.getBean("first");
    }else{
      return context.getBean("second");
    }   

}
```

**Note** : businessCondition depends on business logic, I calculate it.

I dislike this approach because I have injected ApplicationContext in my Service bean,
it looks very weird.

Maybe someone knows better approach ? I will be grateful for advice. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a factory looks a good idea for me as you are planning to inject a implementation on the fly based on business logic. If there is a better solution I would like to hear that.

Comment: I can autowire both services and then depending on condition return first or second as well. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: spring [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) could help here

Comment: Why are both services prototype scoped?

Comment: I believe prototype makes sense if multi-thread applies, spring profiles is a deployment option, but although can be changed in runtime need to reload the context, what I believe it is not a good idea

Comment: Spring profile is useful approach just for System properties. There is a Conditional in Spring. But it's useful when the context starts. My condition can change at runtime.

Comment: I have to use prototype for some reason, dont keep in mind it.

Comment: @Koitoer Nope, prototype beans are used to init `@Configurable`s. This in conjunction with the direct lookup from the context makes me wonder if the OP has a deep enough understandimg of spring.